# How can i get from listView1 all the selected items and add them to string[]?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this code and AllFiles is string array:

```
public string[] AllFiles { get; set; }
```

In this place i'm trying to get all selected items(files in this case).
My listView1 set in the designer for multi select so i can select one single file or more from the listView1.

When i make right click on a file i see the menuStrip1 options.
I wonder if i make multi select of some files and make right click the menu that will be opened by the menuStrip1 will be effective for all selected files or only for the one the mouse cursor is on now ?

```
void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {

                if (listView1.FocusedItem.Bounds.Contains(e.Location) == true)
                {
                    menuStrip1.Show(listView1, e.Location);
                }
            }
        }
```

And then i have the event of menuStrip1 item clicked:

```
void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Upload")
            {
                AllFiles = listView1.SelectedItems
                AllFiles =  listView1.FocusedItem.Text);
                Bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
```

And here i want to add to assign to the AllFiles array the files i selected.

```
listView1.FocusedItem.Text
```

Is only for single file but if i selected more then one file how can i Focus/Get all marked/selected files/items from the listView1 and how to assign them to the array AllFiles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would look something like:

```
        List<String> selected = new List<String>();
        foreach(ListViewItem lvi in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            selected.Add(lvi.Text);
        }
        AllFiles = selected.ToArray();
```